# How to get the list of sheet names of ms-excel?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I have an excel file which has a lot of sheets. How could I get a list of sheet names of ms-excel?

(PS: The office is mac version.)

Comment: from external? from within the document? as a macro? etc etc.

Comment: @akira Within the document. No matter whether use a macro, just want to export a list of names as text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following macro:

```
Sub ListWorkSheetNames()

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
Range("A" & i) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

End Sub
```

For me - works quite well.

([source](http://www.handyexceltips.com/2008/04/14/list-worksheet-names/))

Answer (score 1):

To get the same as above but additionally with hyperlinks taking you to the sheet:

```
Sub ListWorkSheetNames()

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
Range("A" & i) = "=HYPERLINK('" + Sheets(i).Name + "'!A1, """ + Sheets(i).Name + " "")"
Next i

End Sub
```