# How do I create a macro in Excel for Mac?

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2011

I have found this thread on this topic
[How to get the list of sheet names of ms-excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/477800/how-to-get-the-list-of-sheet-names-of-ms-excel)

But I have no idea how to create the macro people are talking about. I will be grateful for your help on how to create the macro with the suggested code.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This really is not a teaching site. There are an abundance of resources online to show you how to achieve what you are looking for. Take a look at **[Create, run, edit, or delete a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-run-edit-or-delete-a-macro-fc5fb55d-124d-4cc7-bae0-111c9c26e234#bmxl)** to see if it can help you get started. Once you have attempted this, update your question with specifics of what you did and where you are stuck. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: @CharlieRB Thank you very much for your answer! I am sorry if I asked an inappropriate question.

Comment: Just trying to help you improve your question, explain why it may not get an answer and point you toward resources so you better understand how this site works. No reason to be sorry. This sight is commonly mistaken as a forum, but our format is different and specific.